# How linux suspend/wakeup works for mach-omap2?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, omap

I'm trying to figure out how suspend/wakeup is implemented for `mach-omap2`, specifically in Linux 2.6.37 targeted for TI OMAP3530/DM3730.

Here's some related code:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c?v=2.6.37

```c
static int omap3_pm_suspend(void)
{
    struct power_state *pwrst;
    int state, ret = 0;

    if (wakeup_timer_seconds || wakeup_timer_milliseconds)
        omap2_pm_wakeup_on_timer(wakeup_timer_seconds,
                     wakeup_timer_milliseconds);

    /* Read current next_pwrsts */
    list_for_each_entry(pwrst, &pwrst_list, node)
        pwrst->saved_state = pwrdm_read_next_pwrst(pwrst->pwrdm);
    /* Set ones wanted by suspend */
    list_for_each_entry(pwrst, &pwrst_list, node) {
        if (omap_set_pwrdm_state(pwrst->pwrdm, pwrst->next_state))
            goto restore;
        if (pwrdm_clear_all_prev_pwrst(pwrst->pwrdm))
            goto restore;
    }

    omap_uart_prepare_suspend();
    omap3_intc_suspend();

    omap_sram_idle();

restore:
    /* Restore next_pwrsts */
    list_for_each_entry(pwrst, &pwrst_list, node) {
        state = pwrdm_read_prev_pwrst(pwrst->pwrdm);
        if (state > pwrst->next_state) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Powerdomain (%s) didn't enter "
                   "target state %d\n",
                   pwrst->pwrdm->name, pwrst->next_state);
            ret = -1;
        }
        omap_set_pwrdm_state(pwrst->pwrdm, pwrst->saved_state);
    }
    if (ret)
        printk(KERN_ERR "Could not enter target state in pm_suspend\n");
    else
        printk(KERN_INFO "Successfully put all powerdomains "
               "to target state\n");

    return ret;
}
```

I'm really struggling to understand how it works.

It seems like, when the suspend procedure runs to after `omap_sram_idle();`, system is already in suspend mode and everything just freezes there, in the context of this function. When it wakes up, it simply continues from `restore:` and restores everything. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System suspend is happening **in the middle** of `omap_sram_idle()`. The second part of `omap_sram_idle()` is actually restoring code. More precisely, actual sleeping is done by `wfi` ARM instruction in `omap34xx_cpu_suspend()` assembler function. Read further for details.

## Suspend path

- take a look at [omap_sram_idle()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c#L348) function implementation
- you can see (judging from comments) that the last line before system falls to sleep is `_omap_sram_idle()` call ([here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c#L441))
- `_omap_sram_idle()` points to [omap34xx_cpu_suspend()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/sleep34xx.S#L187) assembler function, which copied previously to [SRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory) (so it will not be lost during RAM power-off); take a look at next lines of code:

  1. [_omap_sram_idle() assignment](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c#L998) (notice that first parameter that is passed to it is `omap34xx_cpu_suspend` function address)
  2. [omap_sram_push()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/plat-omap/sram.c#L247) implementation; pay attention to [memcpy() call](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/plat-omap/sram.c#L256): `omap_sram_ceil` is start address of SRAM memory, `start` is address of `omap34xx_cpu_suspend() function`
  3. [omap34xx_cpu_suspend()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/sleep34xx.S#L187) implementation; it's the actual function being executed at [this line](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c#L446) (instead of `_omap_sram_idle()`). Take a look at comment above this function:

     ```c
     /*
      * Forces OMAP into idle state
      *
      * omap34xx_suspend() - This bit of code just executes the WFI
      * for normal idles.
      *
      * Note: This code get's copied to internal SRAM at boot. When the OMAP
      *       wakes up it continues execution at the point it went to sleep.
      */
     ```
- actual sleeping is happening in [wfi](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/Chdggedj.html#Cihhigaj) (Wait For Interrupt) ARM instruction (in `omap34xx_cpu_suspend()` function); the processor will sleep and it will wake up only when some IRQ will happen
- there are 2 places in `omap34xx_cpu_suspend()` when `wfi` can be executed:

  - if context save is not required: [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/sleep34xx.S#L215)
  - if context save is required: [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/sleep34xx.S#L595)

## Restore path

Once some wake-up signal happened, CPU will continue to execute instructions just after `wfi` instruction (that have put it to the sleep in the first place). So your system wakes up in `omap34xx_cpu_suspend()` assembler function (starting from `wait_sdrk_ok:` label), then returns back to `omap_sram_idle()` (to [this](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c#L447) line), and then returns back to `omap3_pm_suspend()`, to `restore:` label.

Comment: Great answer! Has this implementation changed over time in later linux versions?

Comment: No, not really. You can navigate the same code in kernel 4.0 sources [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c). I don't see any big difference with 2.6. If you will try and see how much commitment was done to this file last time (`git log -- arch/arm/mach-omap2/pm34xx.c`) -- you will see that pm_suspend code was mostly unchanged since 2.6.

Comment: Here are some related questions, [iMx35 DDR suspend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779633/i-mx35-suspend-cpu-and-ddr2-from-iram) and [Linux idle processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058781/how-does-linux-kernel-wake-idle-processor-up-when-new-task-created).  Os code needs to put things in a special mode for the `wfi` instructions to enter deeper sleeps.  It can be quite complex as DDR can not run code when suspended (and it is often a large current consumer).  So, there are omap specifics  in this answer, but the concepts apply to all Linux ARM cpus.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to check is it possible to stop suspension of a particularity module/device , like SGX module on Jacinto based Board ?

Comment: @Milan You mean, suspend the CPU, but keep some IP core running? Maybe it's possible by modifying its driver code, but I don't see how it could be helpful, without CPU running (it's in `wfi` instruction). See [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/runtime_pm.txt) for details. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @SamProtsenko, Thanks for replying. We have run into as issue where one of our modules doesn't really come out of reset and its state in /sys/power/state is OFF. We have fixed doing this but not sure this is the proper solution to it, https://paste.ubuntu.com/25233104/ .

Comment: @Milan I think it's better to create a new question, describing your issue with details, steps to reproduce, minimal compilable example, etc. Also it's worth to ask it on TI E2E forum.